# How to solve the lan connection in ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?

Tags: lan, wired

I have windows and Ubuntu dual booted in my laptop, the wired Lan gets connected in my windows however it fails to get connected in ubuntu

Comment: Please [edit] and post hardware specifications, namely the Ethernet card/chip. You can check it in Windows' Device Manager.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, and I'll take a look.